# Python - sumar todas las filas de varias columnas

Tags: python

Quiero hacer varias operaciones que son repetidas para varias columnas pero no consigo hacerlo con un *"list comprehension"* o con un bucle.

El dataframe que tengo es `concern_polls` y quiero *reescalar* los porcentajes y las cantidades totales.

```
                                                  text   very  somewhat  \
0    How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  19.00     33.00   
1    How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  26.00     32.00   
2    Taking into consideration both your risk of co...  13.00     26.00   
3    How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  23.00     32.00   
4    How concerned are you that you or someone in y...  11.00     24.00   
..                                                 ...    ...       ...   
625  How worried are you personally about experienc...  33.09     36.55   
626  How do you feel about the possibility that you...  30.00     31.00   
627  Are you concerned, or not concerned about your...  34.00     35.00   
628  Are you personally afraid of contracting the C...  28.00     32.00   
629  Taking into consideration both your risk of co...  22.00     40.00   

     not_very  not_at_all                                                url  
0       23.00       11.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...  
1       25.00        7.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...  
2       43.00       18.00  https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_...  
3       24.00        9.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...  
4       33.00       20.00  https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/202...  
..        ...         ...                                                ...  
625     14.92       12.78  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cIEEkz...  
626     14.00       16.00  https://www.washingtonpost.com/context/jan-10-...  
627     19.00       12.00  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H3uFRD7X0Qttk...  
628     16.00       15.00  https://leger360.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/0...  
629     21.00       16.00  https://docs.cdn.yougov.com/4k61xul7y7/econTab...  

[630 rows x 15 columns]
```

Las variables `very`, `somewhat`, `not_very` y `not_at_all` están representadas en porcentajes sobre la columna 'sample_size', que no se aprecia en la muestra que comparto.
Los porcentajes no siempre suman 100% por lo que quiero reescalarlo

Para ello, doy los siguientes pasos:
calculo la suma de las columnas -> variable `sum`
calculo el tanto por `%`. Este paso podría dejarlo como una variable y no crear una nueva columna en el `df`.
calculo las cantidades finales

El código que tengo hasta ahora es este:

```
sums = concern_polls['very'] + concern_polls['somewhat'] + concern_polls['not_very'] + concern_polls['not_at_all']


concern_polls['Very'] = concern_polls['very'] / sums * 100
concern_polls['Somewhat'] = concern_polls['somewhat'] / sums * 100
concern_polls['Not_very'] = concern_polls['not_very'] / sums * 100
concern_polls['Not_at_all'] = concern_polls['not_at_all'] / sums * 100


concern_polls['Total_Very'] = concern_polls['Very'] / 100 * concern_polls['sample_size']
concern_polls['Total_Somewhat'] = concern_polls['Somewhat'] / 100 * concern_polls['sample_size']
concern_polls['Total_Not_very'] = concern_polls['Not_very'] / 100 * concern_polls['sample_size']
concern_polls['Total_Not_at_all'] = concern_polls['Not_at_all'] / 100 * concern_polls['sample_size']
```

He tratado de plantear la función con *"list comprehension"* pero no lo consigo.

Alguien me podría hacer alguna sugerencia?

Los problemas que me encuentro es que quiero
sumar todas las filas de varias columnas, pero no son todas las del `df`
hacer operaciones repetitivas sobre varias columnas, pero no son todas las del `df`

Muchas gracias.

Comment: quieres sumar los valores de algunas columnas pero de todas las filas?

Comment: @Christian , eso es. De cada una de las columnas que indico, todas sus filas

Comment: quieres crear una nueva columna o reemplazar la existente?(aunque creo que es mejor crear una nueva)

Comment: @Christian, quiero crear una nueva

Comment: Ok, ya tengo una respuesta pero me falta la ultima parte, que contiene la columna `concern_polls['sample_size']`?

Comment: @Christian, son números nada más

Comment: Entonces creo que mi respuesta te ayudara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas cosas que se pueden simplificar, pues existe una función de Python llamada `sum()` la cual hace la operación de suma en un iterable, además se puede usar una compresión de lista para este trabajo.

Primero vamos a indicar que columnas queremos sumar

```py
columnas_sum = ["somewhat","not_very","not_at_all"]
```

Luego  hacemos una compresion de lista, la cual sume todos los valores de la columa y finalmente suma todos los resultados

```py
suma = sum([sum(df[col]) for col in columnas_sum])
```

Finalmente sacamos el nuevo porcentaje y como esto dará un decimal muy largo, lo redondeamos usando la función `round(num,decimals)`, el segundo parámetro es el numero de decimales a obtener.

```py
new_values = [round(df[col]/suma*100,3) for col in columnas_sum]
```

Ahora solo nos queda crear las nuevas columnas, según los datos almacenados en la variable `new_values`, esta variable guarda los valores, algo así `[9.198,8.653,3.98]`, cada uno correspondiente a la columna, por lo que podemos acceder a sus valores como índices.

```py
df['SomeWhat'] = new_values[0]
df['Not_Very'] = new_values[1]
df['Not_at_All'] = new_values[2]

print(df)
```

Teniendo como resultado

```
                                             text  very  somewhat  not_very  not_at_all  SomeWhat  Not_Very  Not_at_All
0  How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil  19.0      33.0      23.0        11.0     9.167     6.389       3.056
1  How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil  26.0      32.0      25.0         7.0     8.889     6.944       1.944
2  Taking into consideration both your risk of co  13.0      26.0      43.0        18.0     7.222    11.944       5.000
3  How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil  23.0      32.0      24.0         9.0     8.889     6.667       2.500
4  How concerned are you that you or someone in y  11.0      24.0      33.0        20.0     6.667     9.167       5.556
...
```

Tendrás que seguir el mismo procedimiento para obtener la columna `Total`, como  esta hace operaciones con la columna `sample_size` y no la has puesto, no he podido hacer el ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias Christian. Lo que veo aquí es que haces un nuevo dataframe y eso es lo que quiero evitar hacer

Comment: @icatalan no se hace un nuevo *DataFrame*, solo se agrega columnas al ya existente

Comment: algo debo estar haciendo mal pero el código me da error en ```suma = sum([sum(columnas_sum[col]) for col in columnas_sum])```

Comment: @icatalan la variable `columnas_sum` solo contiene las columas que se van a tomar en cuenta, en tu caso deberas hacerlo asi `suma = sum([sum(concern_polls[col]) for col in columnas_sum])`

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas comprensiones de listas ni bucles para hacer el cómputo que pides, aunque sí las usaré para crear los nombres de las nuevas columnas que quieres insertar.

Partiendo de una variable que lista qué columnas participan de los cálculos:

```
cols = ['very', 'somewhat', "not_very", "not_at_all"]
```

creo otras dos, con los nombres de las nuevas columnas que se crearán:

```
Cols = [name.capitalize() for name in cols ]  # Mismos nombres pero con inicial mayuscula
Totals = [f"Total_{name}" for name in Cols ]  # Nombres anteriores con Total_ delante
```

Ahora los cómputos que quieres hacer se reducen a tres líneas, gracias a que Pandas opera de forma vectorizada:

```
sums = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
df[Cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x/sums*100)
df[Totals] = df[Cols].apply(lambda x: x/100*df["sample_size"])
```

> **Breve explicación**. La sintaxis `df[lista]` selecciona del dataframe sólo las columnas especificadas en esa lista. El método `sum()` suma todo el sub-dataframe extraído, por defecto suma en vertical pero con `axis=1` lo hará en horizontal que es lo que se desea en este caso.
>
> La función `.apply()` ejecuta la `lambda` en cada columna del sub-dataframe, y devuelve otro dataframe con los resultados, el cual es asignado a un nuevo set de columnas en `df`.

El dataframe resultante sería el siguiente (añadí una columna llamada `"sample_size"` con números aleatorios entre 300 y 1000 para poder completar los cálculos, ya que no proporcionabas los valores de esa columna).

```
>>> pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
>>> print(df)
                                                text   very  somewhat  \
0  How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  19.00     33.00   
1  How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  26.00     32.00   
2  Taking into consideration both your risk of co...  13.00     26.00   
3  How concerned are you that the coronavirus wil...  23.00     32.00   
4  How concerned are you that you or someone in y...  11.00     24.00   
5  How worried are you personally about experienc...  33.09     36.55   
6  How do you feel about the possibility that you...  30.00     31.00   
7  Are you concerned, or not concerned about your...  34.00     35.00   
8  Are you personally afraid of contracting the C...  28.00     32.00   
9  Taking into consideration both your risk of co...  22.00     40.00   

   not_very  not_at_all                                                url  \
0     23.00       11.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...   
1     25.00        7.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...   
2     43.00       18.00  https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_...   
3     24.00        9.00  https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/...   
4     33.00       20.00  https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/202...   
5     14.92       12.78  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cIEEkz...   
6     14.00       16.00  https://www.washingtonpost.com/context/jan-10-...   
7     19.00       12.00  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H3uFRD7X0Qttk...   
8     16.00       15.00  https://leger360.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/0...   
9     21.00       16.00  https://docs.cdn.yougov.com/4k61xul7y7/econTab...   

   sample_size       Very   Somewhat   Not_very  Not_at_all  Total_Very  \
0          841  22.093023  38.372093  26.744186   12.790698  185.802326   
1          648  28.888889  35.555556  27.777778    7.777778  187.200000   
2          936  13.000000  26.000000  43.000000   18.000000  121.680000   
3          451  26.136364  36.363636  27.272727   10.227273  117.875000   
4          823  12.500000  27.272727  37.500000   22.727273  102.875000   
5          552  33.994247  37.548798  15.327717   13.129238  187.648243   
6          312  32.967033  34.065934  15.384615   17.582418  102.857143   
7          438  34.000000  35.000000  19.000000   12.000000  148.920000   
8          570  30.769231  35.164835  17.582418   16.483516  175.384615   
9          803  22.222222  40.404040  21.212121   16.161616  178.444444   

   Total_Somewhat  Total_Not_very  Total_Not_at_all  
0      322.709302      224.918605        107.569767  
1      230.400000      180.000000         50.400000  
2      243.360000      402.480000        168.480000  
3      164.000000      123.000000         46.125000  
4      224.454545      308.625000        187.045455  
5      207.269365       84.608999         72.473392  
6      106.285714       48.000000         54.857143  
7      153.300000       83.220000         52.560000  
8      200.439560      100.219780         93.956044  
9      324.444444      170.333333        129.777778
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero veo que haces un nuevo dataframe y eso es lo que quiero evitar

Comment: No, no estoy haciendo ningún nuevo dataframe. `df` el nombre del dataframe original que cargo y sobre el que hago todas las operaciones. En tu caso se llamaba `concern_polls` pero lo llamé `df` para escribir menos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo que hace que se sume fila por fila

```
concern_polls['Very'] = concern_polls.apply(lambda row: row['very'] / sums * 100, axis=1)
```

Y si desea es que las sumas sean el total de cada una de esas columnas `df`, será de la siguiente manera:

```
sums = concern_polls[['very', 'somewhat', 'not_very', 'not_at_all']].sum().sum()
```